# How do I get top/bottom spacing to be responsive?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to finish up my portfolio page right now. Having an issue getting the top/bottom padding spacing to stay the same on 24" and 13". As you can see from the images below, the 24" inch currently looks how I want it to, with all my elements on the right side directly in the middle. When it becomes 13", the spacing is off and the elements aren't centered. How do I fix this?

24" - http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/jay-portfolio-24-inch-spacing_zpsenaqpzp4.png

13" - http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/jay-portfolio-13-inch-spacing_zps45ygidew.png

HTML FRONT PAGE -

```
<body ng-app="jayPortfolio">

  <!-- NAVBAR -->
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">JAY BITTNER</a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="/portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="/experience">EXPERIENCE</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- LOAD OTHER PAGES HERE -->
  <main>
    <div id='ng-view' ng-view></div>
  </main>
</body>
```

HTML FRONT PAGE PARTIAL -

```
<section id="about" ng-controller="aboutController">    

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="about-left col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      </div>

      <div class="about-right col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

        <div class="about-content">

          <div class="about-content-title">
            <h1><strong>I'M JAY.</strong></h1>
          </div>

          <br />

          <div class="about-content-info" ng-model="about.firstParagraph">
            <p ng-if="about.firstParagraph"><strong>An entrepenurial minded, Full Stack Developer. Whenever I'm up against a challenge that I care about, it gives me a rush. Focusing on the big picture is important to me, but I never forget the smaller details. Anything that is not challenging is boring, and makes me yawn. Anything that is seemingly impossible interests me a lot. I'm ready to get to work.</strong></p>

            <p ng-if="!about.firstParagraph"><strong>Currently seeking a Javascript position, using the MEAN stack, in New York City. Being innovative, ambitious, and hard working are values that are very important to me. I want to join a company that has similar values and has goals of reaching ridiculous levels of success, not just modest realistic ones. I love working with a solid team.</strong></p>
          </div>

          <br />

          <div class="about-button">
            <button ng-if="about.firstParagraph" class="label label-success" ng-click="about.switchParagraph()"><strong>MORE =></strong></button>
            <button ng-if="!about.firstParagraph" class="label label-success"><a href="/portfolio"><strong>VIEW PORTFOLIO</strong></a>
          </div>

          <br />

          <div class="about-personal-info">
            <h4><strong>Email: jaybittner@gmail.com</strong></h4>
            <br />
            <div class="about-icon" ng-repeat="profile in about.profiles">
              <a href="{{ profile.url }}"><img src="{{ profile.icon }}" /></a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

CSS -

```
#about {
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,color-stop(0.12, #061419),
color-stop(0.61, #36875F)
  );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#about .container-fluid, #about .container-fluid .row {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.about-left {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('../../images/jay-ocean.jpg'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 100%;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}

.about-right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.about-content {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-content-title h1{
  font-size: 3.4vw;
}

.about-content-info p {
  font-size: 1vw;
  word-spacing: 0.3vw;
}

.about-button button {
  color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: black;
}

.about-button a {
  color: gray;
}

.about-personal-info h4 {
  font-size: 1vw;
  word-spacing: 0.3vw;
}

.about-icon {
  display: inline;
  word-spacing: 0.3vw;
}

.about-icon img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Can you include the header / navigation part in your HTML, please?

Comment: Sure thing. Just added that now.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be in the navigation bar, where there is a solid `container`, when your page content lies in `container-fluid`.

It's hard for me to throw a straight off working code for you by now, but your issue is the placement of your `navbar-brand`. You could try to center it or adjust it's position via `padding` or `margin` in **media queries**.

To do so, put this in your CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 1199px)
{
   .navbar-brand {
      padding-left: 100px;
   }
}
```

The max width in media query calculates the screen viewport and changes the appearance of the site for something desired by the exact width or height of the page on screen.

With `max-width: 1199px` this media query uses this `padding-left` attribute to `.navbar-brand` when the screen (or the browser window) is showing the page below this width.

You can also work around with this to use with `min-width` or even `height` related viewport settings in CSS.